# How to switch screens in kivymd when there is a list

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I created a music player and I tried to add functionality of switching screens when I click the list it should have switch the screen but it gives me error which I don't know at all.
It says : raise AttributeError(key), also something wrong with "on_press: root.manager.current ='controller'

Sorry if my code kinda messy.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
import os

helper_string = """
ScreenManager:
    MainScreen:
    PlayingScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'list'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDToolbar:
            title: "Demo music player"
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                id: scroll
                on_press: root.manager.current ='controller'


<PlayingScreen>:
    name: 'controller'
    MDLabel:
        text : 'Hello world'
        halight: 'center'

"""

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class PlayingScreen(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MainScreen (name='list'))
sm.add_widget(PlayingScreen (name='controller'))

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.sound = None
        self.theme_cls.theme_style="Dark"
        screen = Builder.load_string(helper_string)
        return screen
        
    def on_start(self):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk('assets'):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith('.mp3'):
                    required_file = file
                    the_location = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, required_file))
                    self.root.ids.scroll.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=the_location, 
                                                                    on_release=self.play_song))

    
    def play_song(self, onelinelistitem):
        the_song_path = onelinelistitem.text
        if self.sound:
            self.sound.stop()
        self.sound = SoundLoader.load(the_song_path)
        if self.sound:
            self.sound.play()
        print(the_song_path)

    

MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy and paste this:[image: I changed only this part:]

Sorry for my late response
Tou must delete "on_press": [image: see this]

This is the correct code:
`MDList: id: scroll on_touch_down: app.root.current ='controller'`

Comment: change the line of "on_press " with "on_touch_down: app.root.current ='controller'"

Comment: I did, just go to link you will see what error is (https://snipboard.io/AMbFD6.jpg)

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, delete "on_press:"

Comment: I did what u said but still the same [error]:( https://snipboard.io/AMbFD6.jpg)

Comment: Yes I did it another way. I used MDDialog instead of screen switching but thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Ok, sorry. Goodbye

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `self.root.current = "insert here the id of screen"`

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering but can u be specific where I should put it, I'm not a senior programmer .

Comment: Change: `root.manager.current ='controller'` with `app.root.current = 'controller' `

Comment: Your error appear because MDList has not option "on_press" try this: `                on_touch_down: app.root.current ='controller'`for me work

Comment: now it says :  AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
I dont know that to do

Comment: Quality answers typically include explanations as to how/why their code addresses OP's issue. I must include links to documentation, and limitations to is usage. Most updating occurs from future visitors who found your explanations/insights helpful in solving their own coding issues.

Answer (score 0):

I used `on_release`, and it worked for me, instead of `on_press`..